# Coupon code Discount should apply for MRP instead of selling price

Tags: magento-1.7

Currently after applying coupon code, discount is applied to selling price. but we want Discount to be applied for **MRP** and not for selling price.

Example :

```
MRP = 200   , Selling Price = 175  
Coupon code discount =  10%
```

**so how Default magento works is = > 10% for 175 [final price = 157.5 ]**,

**but what i need is 10 % for 200. [final price = 180 ]**

so i tried below code as mentioned in [this link](http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.in/2012/01/apply-coupon-discount-on-original-price.html),

**now what i am getting : 175- 20 = 155 as final price**

**but What i need is : 200- 10 = 180 as final price**

is there any Module to achieve this  or what code i need to change to get result?

```
    $item=$observer['item'];
    $rule=$observer['rule'];
    $rule->getDiscountAmount();
    $rulePercent = max(0, 100-$rule->getDiscountAmount());
    echo "<br>--pro id---".$item->getProductId();
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($rule->getData());

    if($rule->getSimpleAction()=='by_percent')
    { 
        $disPer=$rule->getDiscountAmount();
        $product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

        //echo "<br>pro price----".$product->getPrice(); 

        $item->getDiscountAmount();

        $ratdisc=($product->getPrice()*$disPer)/100;
        $DiscountAmount=$ratdisc+$item->getDiscountAmount();
        $item->setBaseDiscountAmount();
        $BaseDiscountAmount=$ratdisc+$item->setBaseDiscountAmount();

        $result = $observer['result'];
        $result->setDiscountAmount($DiscountAmount);
        $result->setBaseDiscountAmount($BaseDiscountAmount);
    }
```

Comment: don't you think customers will confuse if it applied for MRP , instead don't you want to remove selling price....

Comment: @Baby yes, I agree with you but  it is marketing requirement.

Comment: is you guys have plan to give `coupon code` for some customers personally or you guys will publish officially ?

Comment: it will be published officially

Comment: @Baby - Is it possible to do?

Comment: MRP = 200 $, special price = 100 $ , when applied coupon code with 10 % discount , than usually [100-10] = 90 is final price. 
but as you are telling you want to apply discount for original price, than [100- 20 ] = 80 will be final price, do you want this ?

Comment: @Baby in Magento Suppose MRP = 200,  Special price = 175  , Counpon code = 10% then result wille be 200 - 10% = 180. 180 will be the final price.

Comment: may be [this link](http://pradeepkumarrcs.blogspot.in/2012/01/apply-coupon-discount-on-original-price.html) helps....

Comment: @BabyinMagento Thanks I will try to implement

Comment: @BabyinMagento - It helped me a lot but now issue is I want to subtract it from MRP price.

Comment: okay, than please edit question with what you tried & what result you got and what you need, so that someone can help you soon.....

Comment: yes, I have edited the question

Comment: please post code you tried....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45096/discussion-between-jassi-and-baby-in-magento).